# Flask - Get key values from request.get_json()

Tags: python, request, json, flask

I am attempting to get the key values after requesting json data from ajax POST. I succesfully retrieve the data, however I get the error: " AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'".

I have attempted using json.load(data) however, this is also unsuccessful.

```
@app.route('/sendstats', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@crossdomain(origin='*', headers='Content-Type')
def go():
  data= request.get_json()
  keys = sorted(data.keys())
  .....
  return "Search added"
```

Comment: Did you happen to find a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `json.loads()` (note the final `s`)?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the request body in the first place, you might have put a unicode object there instead of str. this can happen for example if you call json.dumps twice on the same input (first time converts the dict to a str, second time converting it to unicode)